# Why I get "undefined" for "load" when I use game.load ? (Vue + Phaser)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, phaser-framework

I started new project with Vue + Phaser but when I try to load assets, "load" and "add" in this.game.load.image returned "undefined".
I try to import the preload function since a JS file but I got the same error.
My Phaser code did'nt return an error if I test it without Vue, It's functionnal.

Game.vue  :

```
import Phaser from 'phaser'
export default {
name: 'Game',
data: () => ({
    game: null,
    sprites: {}
}),
mounted () {
    const self = this
    if (this.game == null) {
        this.game = new Phaser.Game({
            type: Phaser.AUTO,
            width: window.innerWidth,
            height: window.innerHeight,
            antialias: true,
            parent: this.$el,
            physics: {
                default: 'arcade',
                arcade: {
                    gravity: { 
                        y: 300 
                    },
                    debug: false
                }
            },
            scene: {
                preload: function preload() {
                    self.preload(this)
                },
                create: function create() {
                    self.create(this)
                },
                update: function update() {
                    self.update(this)
                },
                render: function render() {
                    self.render(this)
                }
            }
        })
    }
},
methods: {
    preload () {
        this.game.load.setBaseURL('http://labs.phaser.io')

        this.game.load.image('sky', 'src/games/firstgame/assets/sky.png')
        this.game.load.image('ground', 'src/games/firstgame/assets/platform.png')
        this.game.load.spritesheet('dude', 'src/games/firstgame/assets/dude.png', { frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 48 })
        this.game.load.spritesheet('monster', 'src/games/firstgame/assets/dude.png', { frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 48 })
    },
    create (phaser) {
        let self = this
        console.log(self, phaser, this.game)
        this.game.add.image(0, 0, 'sky').setOrigin(0,0).setScale(4);
    },
    listener (e) {
        console.log('listener', e)
    },
    update () {

    },
}
}
```

Sorry for my english mistakes

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you are using Webpack/Vue-CLI?

If that's the case, import those assets as modules and reference the imports in your loader calls.

```
import sky from 'src/games/firstgame/assets/sky.png'

// in your preload method:
this.game.load.image('sky', sky)
```

This is necessary because Webpack needs to replace the path to the image in your source folder with the path to the image in the output directory of your build.

https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management#loading-images

Also, check out my Vue/Phaser Webpack template that has everything nicely set up for you to get going.

https://github.com/Sun0fABeach/vue-phaser3

Comment: If only I had found this sooner....the vue.config.js is what I couldn't find anywhere. This is the only answer I've found that makes images work. Thank you!